# Selecting group of elements from array which satisfies specific condition

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

Consider an array `[1,2,3,4,3,2,4,1,2]`. I have to select a group of elements (find a subarray) whose total is 5. Once a group is selected, those elements should be removed from the array until there is no combination of elements that satisfies the condition. For the given array, the subarrays would be `[1,4] [2,3] [3,2] [4,1]`.

I need ideas on how to write a highly optimized algorithm for this problem.

My actual problem has array of hashes like

```
[
  {name: 'name1', duration: 300.2, song_id: 1},
  {name: 'name2', duration: 412.7, song_id: 2}
  ...
]
```

I have to collect arrays (groups) of songs so that their duration lies, for example, within 29-30 minutes or 9-10 minutes. Duration specified in the example hash are in seconds.

**Update:**

There is no constrain for the number of elements in the selected groups.

Here is another example to understand the problem better. Given array is `[10,20,30,40,50,5,15,25,35,45,55]`, I have to select groups whose total is 50. The answers would be `[10,20,5,15],[50]`

Comment: Do you want help with the Bin packing problem or the Ruby aspects of accessing the array? What have you considered?

Comment: If you need all such groups, this seems awfully exponential.

Comment: I assume you don't want to have fixed size of group in your real case. That's a different magnitude of complexity than the example you provided.

Comment: @ArieShaw the size of group is not fixed. In my example the group have length of 2 but it may be 3,4,5.. depending on the input array.

Comment: @Borsunho I don't need all group(I may at some point, not so sure) But the number groups that I need to find will be specified in advance. As of now it ranges from 5-10.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek I'm not familiar with Bin packaging problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the order doesn't matter (I mean ([4,1]==[4,1])) I have a better solution to bruteforcing combinations.

This is a bruteforcing algorithm

```
def bruteforcing(arr)
  arr.combination(2).find_all{ |x, y| x + y == 5 }.uniq
end
```

This is a better solution (I'ts just an example you could improve). The main idea is to order the Array and search pair by the opposite extremes at first, and stop the search if the sum of values is mayor than 5.

```
    def search(arr)
      ret=[]
      arr.sort!

      while arr != []
        current = arr.pop
        arr.each.with_index do |value, index|
          if current + value == 5
            ret << [value,current]
            arr.delete_at(index)
            break
          elsif current+value > 5
            break
          end
        end
      end
      ret
    end

This is my search.rb (with benchmark)

require "benchmark"

def bruteforcing(arr)
  arr.combination(2).find_all{ |x, y| x + y == 5 }.uniq
end

def search(arr)
  ret=[]
  arr.sort!

  while arr != []
    current = arr.pop
    arr.each.with_index do |value, index|
      if current + value == 5
        ret << [value,current]
        arr.delete_at(index)
        break
      elsif current+value > 5
        break
      end
    end
  end
  ret
end

def bench_times(n)
  Benchmark.bm do |x|
    puts "behc n times #{n}."
    x.report { n.times{bruteforcing( [1,2,3,4,3,2,4,1,2] ) }  }
    x.report { n.times{ search( [1,2,3,4,3,2,4,1,2] ) } }
  end
end

def bench_elements(n)
  puts "bench with #{n} elements."
  Benchmark.bm do |x|
    a=[]
    1_000.times { a<<rand(1..4) }
    x.report { bruteforcing(a) }
    a=[]
    1_000.times { a << rand(1..4) }
    x.report { search(a) }
  end
end

puts bruteforcing([1,2,3,4,3,2,4,1,2]).to_s
puts search([1,2,3,4,3,2,4,1,2]).to_s

bench_times 1
bench_times 5
bench_times 1_000
bench_times 1_000_000

bench_elements(100)
bench_elements(1_000)
bench_elements(100_000)
bench_elements(1_000_000)
```

The output:

```
[[1, 4], [2, 3], [3, 2], [4, 1]]
[[1, 4], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 3]]
       user     system      total        real
behc n times 1.
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000036)
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000013)
       user     system      total        real
behc n times 5.
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000118)
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000037)
       user     system      total        real
behc n times 1000.
   0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.017804)
   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.006673)
       user     system      total        real
behc n times 1000000.
  16.580000   0.020000  16.600000 ( 16.583692)
   5.970000   0.000000   5.970000 (  5.968241)
bench with 100 elements.
       user     system      total        real
   0.210000   0.010000   0.220000 (  0.213506)
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000863)
bench with 1000 elements.
       user     system      total        real
   0.210000   0.000000   0.210000 (  0.212349)
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001539)
bench with 100000 elements.
       user     system      total        real
   0.200000   0.000000   0.200000 (  0.201456)
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001067)
bench with 1000000 elements.
       user     system      total        real
   0.190000   0.010000   0.200000 (  0.199400)
   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.000801)
```

Comment: There is no constrain for the group like only 2 elements, It can be 3,4,5.. only constrain is that the total should be equal to some specified value.

Comment: you can make some  few modifies to that code for that, the idea is the same